# How to add class active for first tab in dynamic li

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to show first tab content after page load. I don't know exact how to add class active for first li and for first content . Here is my code.

```
            <div class="container">
           <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <?php foreach($category->result() as $cate){ ?>
         <li><a data-toggle="tab"  href="#cat<?php echo $cate->id; ?>"><?php                   echo $cate->category_name; ?></a></li>

         <?php } ?>
            </ul> 

     <div class="tab-content">
      <?php foreach($category->result() as $cat){ ?>
        <div id="cat<?php echo $cat->id; ?>" class="tab-pane fade">
         <?php
$catego = $cat->id;
    $servi = $this->db->select('*')->from('sundaland_services')->where('service_category_id',$catego )->get()->result();
    ?>
  <p>
  <?php foreach($servi as $ser11){ ?>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="hovereffect">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/services/original/<?php echo $ser11->service_image; ?>" alt="">
                    <div class="overlay">

                        <a class="btn-thm btn-xs" href="<?php echo base_url();?>services/main_services_detail/<?php echo $ser11->id;?> ">Read more <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>

               <h4 style="font-size: 16px!important;"><?php echo $ser11->service_title; ?></h4>
                    <p class="details"><?php echo word_limiter($ser11->service_description, 15); ?></p>
            </div>
 <?php  }
   ?>

   </p>
       </div>
       <?php } ?>

     </div>
      </div>
```

I want that first tab open by default after page load. How to do this? Is there any need to add javascript for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('li').first().addClass('active');
```

It will add active class to first li.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav-tabs li:first").addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Kindly upload your code in JS Fiddle so i can resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using `document.ready` class. My code is when I click on menu button it opens the menu. I copy that click function and place it in the `document.ready` scope so when the document is ready, the loaded menu opens automatically:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu-button").click(function() {
        if ($(".menu-button").hasClass("active")) {
            $(".menu-button").removeClass("active");
            $(".menu-items").addClass("hide");
        } else {
            $(".menu-button").addClass("active");
            $(".menu-items").removeClass("hide");
        }
    });

    $(".menu-button").click();

}); // scope of document.ready
```